# What happened to that guy that was going to nag people into writing blog posts?

Tags: discussion, blog

TL;DR (*): he screwed up.

The start of the blog wasn't exactly what I expected - after much doubt about whether there was content, we were flooded with it, and the problem wasn't getting people to write, it was trying to figure out how to organise things so that the posts didn't all collide (**).

I had been (foolishly) assuming that content would keep popping up (much of the time it just got posted without me doing anything, and the first I heard of the post would be the tweet), and so I stopped worrying about it, other than trying to figure out the organisation issue.  About a month ago, something happened, and this reversed, and we were suddenly (or at least so it seemed) at the (originally expected) nothing to post point.  This caught me by surprise, a lot.

I've been busy with other stuff (I've only caught up with the recent questions & answers over the last week) and kept failing to get on top of this.

Firstly: **my apologies**.  I said that I'd take this on, and haven't done it well.  Secondly: if anyone wants the 'chief nag' role, I have no objection at all to giving it up (I would still like to edit/contribute).

If no-one else is going to seize power, then I'd prefer to try and rectify my mistake than to have the blog languish.  My plan is:

1. Talk to Brett White about being the carrot (grants) to my stick (nagging).  See if he can pull out some quick posts from people that have grants already.
2. Give up on the organisation issue for the moment, until content is flowing again.
3. Write a post tomorrow so that there's fresh content again (not the Harry Potter one I have in draft; I'll finish that in a few days).  I was thinking something about [FSL](http://www.tommerritt.com/2011/10/30/fsl-tonight-week-0-2011-season-preview/).
4. Catch up on whatever's in the chat room that I've missed, and try to figure out some way to work the chat room into my routine so that I'll see anything there regularly.
5. Chase up the few draft posts to see what can be done about getting them finished.
6. Start hitting up the people that originally volunteered to write and those that have written already, to see if they can write something soon.
7. Publish these at a rate of two per week, unless something comes up that needs more (e.g. an event).

(*) I wasn't sure where to post this, since it isn't really a question (although I phrased it as one and broke the rules by answering it in the text!).  It seemed easiest to put it here; apologies if that isn't right.

(**) After much looking, I ended up nowhere with this.  No useful suggestions from wordpress.se, and now I'm stuck in terms of SE (can't ask on webapps.se or meta.so because no cross-posting; can't offer a bounty because no rep on that site, and no real way to earn any - I'd happily donate some of my scifi.se rep, but that's not possible).  I tried to find something outside of SE, but didn't have any luck.  My feeling at the moment is that Trello is  used as the public/transparent face (and we rely on the notifications there and email).

Comment: Great! I feel a bit at fault too, as I was gung ho about the blog when I started here...then got busy. I support this initiative, and will do what I can to help!

Comment: As an addendum: I felt semi-ok about missing anything in the blog chat room because I figured if anyone wanted me specifically they'd mention me and I'd get an inbox note.  However, it turns out that isn't the case, and I was flagged.  So more apologies (to @neilfein in particular) for that.

Comment: @Tony - do you want more of original content, or more "SE Q&A related" content like featured Qs and As?

Comment: @DVK *any* content, really.  I don't think it's my call as to the nature of it.

Comment: The chat room expired (I think), so that part can be disregarded.

Comment: @TonyMeyer don't be too hard on yourself, the same thing happened to both the SU blog as well. Which is exactly why it should be easier for the community to pitch in and not depend on one person to organize things.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems no-one wants to take the job, so...

1. Talked (well, emailed) to Brett; he's happy to help and provided a list of grant recipients versus blog posters and I've asked if any of them are interested in writing something (via comments in their answer to the grant post, which I think works best for communication).
2. Brett said he'd try and do some regular (comic-focused) writing also.
3. I think the chat room expired.  C'est la vie.
4. I've written up a few posts, so there will be at least one per week for a little while (unfortunately all from me, but I'll intersperse with others if there's more content coming).  Perhaps the seemingly-soon move from beta will help inspire.
5. There was only one draft - either some were removed or I incorrectly remembered there being more.  I've asked what can be done to help finish that off (in a comment on a meta post; didn't really know what the best communication method was here).